# Customizing the style of UWP TimePicker (Flyout)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I'm trying to misuse the `TimePicker` control as a timespan picker by setting the `ClockIdentifier` property to `24HourClock` (24 hour range is quite appropriate for my needs).

The only problem is that I don't think the UI is quite clear enough without headers on the `Flyout` to say that the first column is hours and the second column is minutes.

I have successfully customised the `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` by adding my customised style to the `Application`/`Application.Resources`/`ResourceDictionary` element of my `App.xaml`, but this applies to every `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` that is displayed. I'm not always misusing the `TimePicker` control so I'm trying to find a way that I can selectively apply this template.

How can I opt in to this template, rather than applying it to every single `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` that is displayed by a `TimePicker`? I am creating the `TimePicker` class in code, not XAML in case it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` is used in the `TimePicker`'s code behind. You could not found any key words about `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` in the `TimePicker` xaml code. If you custom `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter` style in `Application.Resources`, it will be global. And I don't think it is a good practice that placed the tooltip in the `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter`. This design may not give the user the most direct information at the fist time. I suggest you could place the tooltip in the [`HeaderTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepicker.headertemplate).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TimerDateTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Hour" FontSize="13"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="minute" FontSize="13"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Usage**

```
<TimePicker ClockIdentifier="24HourClock" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TimerDateTemplate}">
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can see it would be useful for a user to know that they are choosing hours/minutes without having to open the flyout first. For the benefit of anyone else who may find this question and has a more legitimate usecase; there's no way to customize the TimePickerFlyoutPresenter without applying the style globally?

Comment: Emm, you could give the key to the style of `TimePickerFlyoutPresenter`, but it can be used in `TimePicker` directly.